# Tinymce doesn't save the text as it was submitted

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I have set tinymce in my website so that the user can use the toolbar while writing text as well as to upload a picture. Unfortunately I have realized the problem related to tinymce.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 tinymce.init({
 selector: "#market-product_info, #market-delivery_info, #market-facility_info",
 language_url: '/frontend/web/js/tinymce/langs/zh_CN.js',
 menubar:true,
 statusbar: true,
 relative_urls : false,
 branding: false,
 plugins: [
           "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
           "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
           "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor",
           "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
           "save"
 ],
  toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor |styleselect | link unlink anchor |link image | preview code ",
  image_advtab: true,   
  // enable title field in the Image dialog


 image_title: true, 
  // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
  automatic_uploads: true,
  // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
  // images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
  file_picker_types: 'image', 
  // and here's our custom image picker
  file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
    // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
    // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
    // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
    // once you do not need it anymore.

    input.onchange = function() {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    input.click();
  }
  });   
});
```

The problem is when a user creates a table or uses any toolbar options (bold, italic, text color or etc.) and submits, in the database the information is received as the user inserted, however if the user wants to edit the info and resubmit, then in the textarea all the words are just displayed without any table or any toolbar features. I would like to have it in a way that the user finds his/her text as it was submitted before if he/she wants to edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create textarea :

```
<textarea style="width: 100%;" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
```

then set content of the textarea :

```
$('#description').html('<table><tr><th>user info table</th></tr></table>');
```

then init the tinyMCE :

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // input tinyMCE options
    ...
});
```